# Backup TDE database to restore unencrypted on 2016

Tags: encryption, backup, restore

We are in a process from migrating SQL Server 2008 R2 enterprise version (with encryption)  to 2016 standard version (without encryption). Currently we are testing on a dev server. I tried to turn off the encryption, take a backup, copy it to the dev server and restore it there.

But then I got the error as the certificate is missing. So I backed up the certificate and key and tried restoring the database using that but it said that the functionality is not available in this version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop the encryption key as well as disable encryption to move to a platform that doesn't support TDE. This is the code I use for that purpose.

```
USE MASTER
GO
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName
SET ENCRYPTION OFF
GO
USE DatabaseName
GO
DROP DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY
GO
```